# Socket API connection between Frappe and Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, frappe

I am creating a mobile app using flutter as front-end and frappe as back-end (i tried in local site). In which i want to create a socket API connection for realtime updates. But i can't get any response or any errors also there is no request log in the bench log.

I have used `web_socket_channel` and `socket_io_client` packages, but nothing happens

Did anyone knows how to make it work?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched Realtime events on Frappe. It looks like Frappe using Socket IO for Realtime events. So you have to use `socket_io_client` package on Flutter side. I am using socket IO on my current project.

First import package with prefix: `import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;`

Then define the socket with this code: `IO.Socket socket = IO.io("socket_url", IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).enableForceNew().build());`

Then listen events on initState with this code block

```
  void initState() {
socket.onConnect((data) => log("connected"));
socket.on("event_name", (data) {
  //handle event
});
super.initState();}
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Thanks it Works, but we also need to pass headers `.setExtraHeaders({....})` and also `socket.connect();`.

Comment: I am not sure but I think socket.onConnect also connect to socket without this function because my code is working without socket.connect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/websocket_universal
There you can track all the events that happen during connection

```
/// 1. Create webSocket handler:
  final textSocketHandler = IWebSocketHandler<String, String>.createClient(
    'wss://ws.postman-echo.com/raw', // Postman echo ws server
    SocketSimpleTextProcessor(),
  );

  /// 2. Listen to webSocket messages:
  textSocketHandler.incomingMessagesStream.listen((inMsg) {
    print('> webSocket  got text message from server: "$inMsg" '
        '[ping: ${textSocketHandler.pingDelayMs}]');
  });
  textSocketHandler.outgoingMessagesStream.listen((inMsg) {
    print('> webSocket sent text message to   server: "$inMsg" '
        '[ping: ${textSocketHandler.pingDelayMs}]');
  });

  /// 3. Connect & send message:
  await textSocketHandler.connect();
  textSocketHandler.sendMessage('Hello server!');
  await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));

  // 4. Disconnect & close connection:
  await textSocketHandler.disconnect('manual disconnect');
  textSocketHandler.close();
```